# Matlab convert RBG color to decimale value

Tags: matlab

So I have `c = imread('foto.png')` and I would like to convert it to a decimale value system. Is their a built-in function?

Comment: You will have to be more specific about how you want to convert it. There is an infinite number of ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    I = imread('foto.png');        
    I2 = im2double(I);
```

Hope this helps